# Animate while move to a new section in a same page in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$('#skip-intro').on("click", function() {
  var header = $('.navbar').innerHeight();
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $('#intro').offset().top - header
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#intro" id="skip-intro">Get to Know</a>
<div class="section-block" id="intro">
  ----content------
</div>
```

Here, Help me find out why animation property is not working while moving down to the below section.

Comment: Do you want to scroll down to the certain div or section on click event as per your code above ?

Comment: To the certain section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use it like this.

```
<header class = 'navbar'>test</header>
<a href="#intro" id="skip-intro">Get to Know</a>
<div class="section-block" id="intro" style = "margin-top: 300px;">
----content------
</div>
```

Script

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#skip-intro').on("click", function(){
        var header = $('.navbar').innerHeight();
    console.log(parseInt($('#intro').offset().top) - parseInt(header))
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: parseInt($('#intro').offset().top) - parseInt(header) }, 1000);
    });
  });

</script>
```

Please note in order to scroll animate to a certain div position it should be within that position for scroll to work, as per your html your `div section` block is already on top so it won't animate as it's currently visible on that position.

Comment: Even if there are multiple buttons with same id id="skip-intro", it won't work right?

Comment: Don't use same `id` for multiple div or items as it won't work at all, it works well with `class` only, after using same class `skip-intro` you can loop through it to check the specific click event

Comment: I don't like that kind of code because it's not object oriented.

Comment: So, when id can be used?

Comment: @PonnaveenS Id's need to be unique. The name says it. It's an identifier. You cant identify an element with it if it's not unique.

Comment: @MarkBaijens is correct, you should know what an attribute actually specifies

Answer (score 2):

Original here: [Find it here](https://blog.kulturbanause.de/2015/12/animiertes-scrolling-smooth-scrolling-jquery/) (But it's in german)

```js
$('a[href*="#"]').on('click',function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var target = this.hash;
 var $target = $(target);
 $('html, body').stop().animate({
  'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
 }, 900, 'swing', function () {
  window.location.hash = target;
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#exp">Href</a>
<div style="height:1000px; background:red;"></div>
<div id="exp" style="background:green; text-align:center;">jdaslkasd</div>
```